# CSS breaking in host site

Tags: html, css, hosting, break

I'm having a weird issue where I'm sure I've written the CSS fine, however the browser isn't picking up the classes.

When checking the file on my hosting provider I see that the classes seem to be registered wrongly. I'm thinking the issue might be here.

[classes shown with different ui colouring to others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf9O8.png)

Anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: Can you share some of the markup? Maybe in a JSFiddle or CodePen?

Answer (score 0):

> When checking the file on my hosting provider I see that the classes seem to be registered wrongly. I'm thinking the issue might be here.

Codes are fine. Your host probably render the colours of the code wrongly.
But i don't see you use the `.hero-home` anywhere on http://www.jardox.com/. Probably the reason why you didn't see any change?

Edit: There's some problem with the characters. change them to utf-8?

[image]